# There is no console output from thread. Thread doesn't work?

Tags: java, multithreading, java-threads

```
class myRunnable implements Runnable {

    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("run");
    }

}

public class TestThread {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable threadJob = new myRunnable();
        Thread t = new Thread(threadJob);
        t.start();
        for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
            System.out.println("main");
        }

    }
}
```

Result in the console:

main
main
main
main
...
main
main
main
main

I can't find any "run" word, this means the run method didn't run. Can somebody explain that for me. Thank you.

PS: when i<10, i<100, i<1000, i<10000, I can find the "run" word, but when i<100000 then I can't find the "run" word, that's just weird

[image]

Comment: How many "main" words do you see? If your console only shows the last 100 lines (for example), the "run" word may have gone outside the range of the buffer

Comment: To just test threading, decrease the loop count, so you can easily inspect the output. Test it with `i < 10` for example; you then will see the expected behavior.

Comment: And why don't you just print "run"?

Comment: It's there, remove sysout from main to see it - but leave the loop

Comment: change i to 10, it would be more comfortable to read console output, so you just overdid with loop counter :)

Comment: when i<10, i<100, i<1000, i<10000, I can find the "run" word, but when i<100000 then I can't find the "run" word, that's just weird

Comment: Yes, because your console log is limited.

Comment: thats _exactly_ how it is supposed to work, you just discovered something called a "console buffer" - keep it in mind once you continue your exploration-quest, it may be important someday.

Comment: I suggest you redirect your output to a file and check the file, to make sure.

Comment: @specializt: Thank you :D, I have got the answer. It's all about how console buffer works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Run` has been printed out. But your console-buffer is not large enougth.

Change the Console-configuration to unlimited buffer.[image]

Comment: I have unchecked "Limit console output" and it works well, I can find the "run" word, thank you again :D

Answer (score 1):

First of all, Yes, Your code actually prints "run".
Just make this little change below and You´ll see it.

A more rigorous test, If You can see it in a different way, is to send the strings to a text file instead of the console. You will certanly find the word "run".

```
class myRunnable implements Runnable {

  @Override
  public void run() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("run");
  }

}

public class TestThread {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Runnable threadJob = new myRunnable();
    Thread t = new Thread(threadJob);
    t.start();
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
      System.out.println("main");
      try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
      }
      catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation runs just fine. You just don't see your `run` message because there hasn't been any thread switch just yet.

The problem is that the action on which you examine the threads is too short. You can insert a `Thread.sleep(2000);` for example to check it out.

Comment: I don't think so, probably "run" is printed and he's just missing it.

Comment: your statement about "thread switch" doesnt make any sense whatsoever.  Im guessing you were referring to CONTEXT SWITCHING - which is entirely managed by the VM and has only little influence on THREAD EXECUTION, from a high-level standpoint every thread appears to run simultaneously and concurrently so _output_ to  `System.out` will show up nigh-instantly, maybe it will show up on line 3 or 4 (pretty early during runtime), depending on the current system-load.

Comment: @specializt Well, no, this answer does make sense in fact. The proper definition is actually *"thread context switching"*, so in fact his use is more specific than yours ("context switching" could also refer to "process context switching", so it is highly ambiguous). And no, JVM doesn't switch the threads, the OS does (thread creation are native calls, you can check the source code for Thread class). And yes, it *appears* to run simultaneously but might be or not.

Answer (score 0):

I find this wired that you can't find a `run` in your output, the thing is that you should understand how the java thread mechanism works, the `main` thread will **not** wait for the *child* thread to complete their work, unless you make it specific, thus whether or not the child complete before the `main` thread complete (and exit) is not expectancy.

if you do want the `main` thread to wait for the `child` thread to complete, you can make it specific by:

```
 t.start();
 t.join();
```

You should have to catch some exception to make this work.

But I think it should be high ratio that you *should* see a `run` printed in your original code. because it seems the main thread is more time consuming.
regardless of this, there is nothing to blame if your jvm behave like this. the thread executing order is not insured by the standard anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add a delay of one second within the loop as displayed below:

```
class myRunnable implements Runnable {

    public void run() {
        System.out.println("run");
    }

}

public class TestThread {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable threadJob = new myRunnable();
        Thread t = new Thread(threadJob);
        t.start();
        for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
            System.out.println("main");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}
```